# How to change the position of buttons in uitoolbar in ios and set a badge for button to show the counts

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitoolbar

I am having a toolbar and in that i have 3 buttons i gave the code as below

```
UIButton *likeImage = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [likeImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    [likeImage setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"likeIconDefault"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [likeImage addTarget:self action:@selector(likeImagePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *likeImageButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:likeImage];
    UIButton *commentImage = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [commentImage setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 30, 30)];
    [commentImage setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"commentIcon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [commentImage addTarget:self action:@selector(commentImagePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *commentImageButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:commentImage];
    UIButton *dislikeImage = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 NSArray *buttonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: likeImageButton, commentImageButton, nil];
```

position of the button is not changing even after giving different values for X and Y coordinates

Comment: show your output image

Comment: The UIToolbar doesn't use the frame to position the buttons. If you need spacing between the buttons you'll need to add ```UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace``` between them. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6798629/2315974

Comment: Thank you it helped

Comment: i need to set a badge above the like buttons to show the like count..can you help me